# Como puedo hacer un calculo de fecha transcurrido

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

basicamente tengo un imput de tipo date donde el usuario coloca la fecha en la que ingreso en la empresa, luego de eso quiero que muestre en otro input el tiempo transcurrido (basicamente algo asi: 1 año 3 meses, 0 año 6 meses), a la fecha actual. Quisiera hacer esto con php y ajax pero no se como hacerlo

[image: basicamente es esto]

Comment: has considerado hacerlo en javascript? necesitas guardar registro de estos dos datos o solo que se muestren?

Comment: Hola lesther gonzalez, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza Ajax y PHP solo en el caso de que realmente necesites interactual con el servidor como, por ejemplo, si necesitas guardar tal diferencia en una base de datos.

En el caso de, simplemente querer calcular la diferencia, la forma más práctica y eificiente de hacerlo sería usando Javascript para obtener la diferencia entre el tiempo seleccionado y el actual.

Para lanzar tal función, necesitas introducir un evento onchange='return comprobar_fecha()' en el campo de la fecha y una función javascript tal que:

```
function comprobar_fecha(){
    var fecha = new Date(document.getElementByID('fecha_form').value);
    var fecha_actual = new Date();
    var diferencia = fecha_actual - fecha; 
    var diferenciaDias = Math.ceil(diferencia/ (1000 * 3600 * 24));  // Paso la diferencia a horas
    document.getElementById('horas_trabajadas').value = diferenciaHoras;
}
```

Comment: intente con el consejo que me has brindado amigo pero de igual manera no me funciono

Comment: @lesther-gonzalez En el tag HTML de ambos formularios debes de introducir un id. En mi ejemplo, el tag del formulario que recoge la fecha actual debería de incluír _id="fecha_form"_ y, en la diferencia debería de incluir _id="fechas_trabajadas"_. Estos identificadores los puedes modificar como tú quieras, pero deben de ser consecuentes con el Javascript. Si ya has tenido en cuenta esto y sigue fallando, dime qué es lo que falla y te intentaré ayudar.